# Are settings unique to projects in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have two projects in PyCharm 4.5.2.  When I change some deployment settings (e.g., add or delete a server) in one project, they also change in the other.  Is this the way it is supposed to work?  Is there a way I should be doing this so that the settings are specific to each project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm support explained that (as of v 4.5.3), there is a checkbox option in Deployment Settings for "Visible only for this project".